# How to correct the time on a Red Hat EL6 server? Clock is almost 3 hours behind

Tags: linux, redhat, time

This did not work:

```
[~]: sudo /usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org
19 Feb 08:03:26 ntpdate[6939]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting
```

So, I'm not sure how to proceed... also tried this to no avail:

```
[~]: sudo service ntpd restart
Shutting down ntpd:                                        [  OK  ]
Starting ntpd:                                             [  OK  ]
```

Then just tried stopping the ntpd service in order to update it:

```
[~]: sudo service ntpd stop
Shutting down ntpd:                                        [  OK  ]
[~]: sudo /usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org
19 Feb 08:09:20 ntpdate[7005]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message from `ntpdate` told you why it didn't work, but for some reason you didn't act on that information.

You should do what it suggested and stop the ntp server first, then try it again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried it though, and got the error as seen above in the edited question.

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the Internet and not firewalled?

Comment: I can ping pool.ntp.org... so I think I'm good.

Comment: @Marcus: `I can ping XY` is not a valid test for this. I can ping `pool.ntp.org` as well, but NTP is still firewalled here...

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct, I think my org has external ntp blocked.  I found an internal NTP server after asking around and the ntpdate command just ran fine.  Problem solved.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remember to configure `ntpd` to your internal server.